# code in InnerHTML doesnt show up on onclick

Tags: javascript, dom

Hey guys I'am making a tic tac toe game and when the user click on the box I want an X or an O to show up. How ever I;am having trouble with this

```
   window.onload = function(){

      var playerOne = {
   played : false,
   turn : false,
   click: "X"
       }

      var playerTwo = {
    played : false,
    turn : false,
    click: "O"
       }



    window.onload = function(){
   var box1 = document.getElementByClassName('box1');
       box1.addEventListener("click", play)
    }
    var play = function(){
  playerOne.turn = true;

   if(playerOne.turn = true){
      box1.innerHTML = playerOne.click;
   }

   playerOne.played = true;
      }
      };
```

When I click inside the box I'am expecting to see and X show up it doesn't can anyone help?

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are comparison. E.g. `if(playerOne.turn = true)`

Comment: box1[0].innerHTML =  playerOne.click;

Comment: Remove that `if(playerOne.turn = true)` clause, it has zero meaning there even with proper `===` or `==` comparison operators. Because of this in prev line **playerOne.turn = true;**

Answer (score 0):

Use ==  to check the condition.

if(playerOne.turn == true)